# Remove rigth bar from Levelplot

Tags: graph, scale, crop, levelplot

I'm trying to remove the right bar from a levelplot, the one that says the scale in colors.
I don't know if there's some way to crop the graph or create a custom function that doesn't print that.

Here is a simple levelplot:

```
  data(mtcars)
  cars.matrix <- as.matrix(mtcars[c(2:8)])
  cars.corr <- cor(cars.matrix)
  levelplot(cars.corr)
```

Answer (score 5):

You simply add `colorkey=FALSE` to the levelplot function.

```
require(lattice)
data(mtcars)
cars.matrix <- as.matrix(mtcars[c(2:8)])
cars.corr <- cor(cars.matrix)
levelplot(cars.corr, colorkey=FALSE)
```